# PowerShell: Sorting CPU usage to display process taking 2% and above

Tags: powershell

What cmdlet can you use in PowerShell to sort CPU usage to 2% and above. I need the output to display only processes with CPU usage 2% and above

Answer (score 0):

I will use `Get-Counter`:

```
(Get-Counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time').CounterSamples | ? {$_.CookedValue -ge 2}
```